# ZF2 - Form created by factory call needs url parameter passing to service

Tags: forms, zend-framework2, factory

I've got a form in a zf2 CMS application with a standard select list populated by a service and a bespoke form element also populated by a service, the form is setup using a factory call in Module.php:

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'ElmContent\Form\WebpageForm' => function ($sm) {
                    $service1 = $sm->get('parentPagesService');
                    $service2 = $sm->get('categoryService');
                    $form    = new Form\WebpageForm;
                    $form->setService($service1, $service2);

                    return $form;
                },
```

The categoryService is used to populate my bespoke form element (a list of categories from another table) - if I am editing a page in my CMS then when I'm building the list of categories, I want to reference another table and see which ones have been associated, to do this I need to pass in the page id from the url, e.g.:

http://cms.local/pages/edit/100 where 100 is the page id and can then be passed in to the categoryService:

```
$this->getCategoryAssociationsTable()->findByPageId(100);
```

More code can be provided if needed, but essentially, 2 form elements are populated by data from db tables so I setup using a factory call, the second element is bespoke formatted list of checkboxes and I want to set them as checked when editing if they were selected previously. To do this, I need to pass the pageId from the url, but can't see where to do this when setting up the form the way I am.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Personally i don't really understand the question. You have a service to create the checkboxes, do you? That service should be able to tell if those Checkboxes are checked or not oO - Furthermore `setServices()` is not good. Name two Setters `setPageService()` and `setCategoryService()`

Comment: Thanks Sam, I can see your point about two methods to set the service(s) - the service for categories happily gets all categories, but I need it to pick up a parameter from the url. Maybe the rest was just confusing the issue, if I call a service, how do I get the URL params in it? Cheers

Comment: Pass it from the Controller `$form = $sm->get('my-form'); $form->setRequest($this->getRequest());` The Request object would contain all information you need i suppose?

Comment: That makes perfect sense - a fresh pair of eyes on the problem. Thanks!

Comment: If the question is answered with above comment, could you write it down in an answer and accept that as the solution? Now this question is still marked as open.

Comment: I couldn't see an option to just accept the answer - is the process to copy an answer and then 'Answer your own question'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it from the Controller $form = $sm->get('my-form'); $form->setRequest($this->getRequest()); The Request object would contain all information you need i suppose? – Sam Jan 20 at 18:39